# How can I separate function type return type and arguments in template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to pass a function type (e.g. `int(float)`) to a class template that separates the return type from the variable arguments list:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class CallFunction
{
public:
    R operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << ("" << ... << (args << "\n"));
        return R{100};
    }
};

int main()
{
    CallFunction<int(float)> cf;
    std::cout << "return value: " << cf(200.f) << "\n";
}
```

I realize the code above doesn't work. In this case, `R` equals `int(float)` instead of just `int` like I expect. Here's the [live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vCLG7k60pwzaQdSH).

I've seen template trickery like this before and it actually worked somehow. I've seen a lot of answers on SO regarding how to do this but it requires a valid function pointer. Here, I'm specifying the function type directly, so `decltype` solution doesn't seem to be applicable here.

How can I accomplish this? I can use up to C++17 for my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int(float)` is a single type (specifically, a function type), so your template needs to take just one type. But then you can use a partial specialization to have the return type and argument types deduced.

```
template <typename>
class CallFunction; // This primary template is not defined.

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class CallFunction<R(Args...)>
{
public:
    R operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << ("" << ... << (args << "\n"));
        return R{100};
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah, this is the piece I was missing. Thank you!! Is there a mechanism to turn `CallFunction` into a traits class whereby I can access `R` and `Args` externally from another object?

Comment: @void.pointer: You can't access a parameter pack like that. If a type is a template over a pack, the only way to access a pack is to instantiate a template that takes the same pack, using deduction to pass that pack (function or class template deduction).

Comment: Right. So you could have a `std::tuple<Args...>` type in the traits, and then other templates would need to "unpack" that tuple type in some way.